# Disable SqlError Reporting on 500 Error for a Production App

Tags: haskell, yesod

When there is a `500` error due to a bad query, Yesod displays the sql query on the page or parts of it. While this has been very helpful in development, I would like to avoid it in production. Is there a way to just display Internal Server Error and no other details?

Chances of having an error with sql is very low but it can still happen if a rogue user tries to come up with a badly formed input (the error message below is just a contrived example to illustrate the issue). There are DB constraints in place to avoid storing these bad inputs but the error message seems to be giving clues about the query, which I would like to avoid (I have seen larger parts of the query in some instances unlike the one below).

```
SqlError {sqlState = "42703", sqlExecStatus = FatalError, 
sqlErrorMsg = "... duplicate key value (1480, 9, 3) violates unique constraint ...", 
sqlErrorDetail = "", sqlErrorHint = ""}
```

I would like to avoid throwing a lot of try/catch-type blocks just to prevent these edge cases. A simple solution would be not display the sqlerror messages. Any thoughts on how I could do it? I am using Keter to deploy my app.

```
# Keter.yaml
exec: ../dist/build/MyApp/MyApp
args:
     - production
host: www.example.com
```

**Update**: Here is a simple errorHandler to address this issue per Michael's answer.

```
 -- Matching only InternalError. All other errors are 
 -- sent to the defaultErrorHandler as-is 
 newErrorHandler (InternalError msg) = do  
     $(logWarn) (append "Error Response: " $ pack (show (InternalError msg)))
     defaultErrorHandler (InternalError "Custom message here") 
 newErrorHandler (errMsg) = defaultErrorHandler errMsg
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the default error handler in your Yesod typeclass using [errorHandler](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130829-168/yesod-core/Yesod-Core.html#v%3aerrorHandler). The default value is [defaultErrorHandler](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130829-168/yesod-core/Yesod-Core.html#v%3adefaultErrorHandler), which displays the full value of the exception thrown. You can instead replace that with whatever information you want, conditional on the `development` value provided by the scaffolded site.

If you wanted to get a bit fancier, I'd recommend logging each exception thrown into your database and generating a random token, then displaying that token to the user on the error handler page. That way, the user can provide you that information so that you can better debug your application.

Comment: Thank you, Michael. Great tip about the random token to debug later. I have updated my question with the simple error handler I used for now in case others find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Using `newErrorHandler` did not work for me, so I instead solved it this way:

```
-- Foundation.hs

instance Yesod App where

  errorHandler (InternalError e) = do
    $(logWarn) e
    fmap toTypedContent $ defaultLayout $ do
      setTitle "Example site"
      $(widgetFile "error")
  errorHandler other = defaultErrorHandler other
```

And then create a custom error template in `templates/error.hamlet`…

```
$newline never

<h1>Internal Error
<p>Sorry, something has gone wrong.
```

You can add more error handers, pattern matching on the type of error. If you remove the `other` pattern, the compiler should tell you your pattern match is inexhaustive and provide some more patterns to match against.